# Render windows on other desktops

Tags: windows, winapi, render, desktop, sandbox

I am experimenting with windowstations and desktops. I want to automate programs on other desktops. 
The problem:

It need image recognition. But programs on other desktops cannot be rendered. ( Get pixel color from window device context )

But some programs like sandboxie run programs on other windowstations/ desktops too. It would be strange if the target window 
just switches to the main desktop and could then attack other windows by window messaging.

So I guess the window is just "re-rendered" on a representive window. 
If this is correct, how does sandboxie receive the rendered window on the other desktop when it doesnt render?

Or am I wrong in principle? Or can one render a window on other desktops? Or is it a "low-level-driver-thing"?

can someone please disband my confusion Smile

Thank you very much

Comment: By my review, sandboxie does not run programs on other desktops.  Can you point to some documentation that suggests otherwise?   Incidentally, one option that can be used is remote desktop connection to a VM.

Comment: unfortunatly I cant provide any official documentation but after all I have read about sandboxes I assumed it.

Comment: unfortunatly I cant provide any official documentation but after all I have read about sandboxes I assumed it. I know it for sure from other sandbox-implementations like adobe. And I know for sure, that sandboxie creates a windowstation which is the hirachical parent for any desktop. And it makes some sense as otherwise the application could send window-messages to other windows on the same desktop wich is an unacceptable security issue. But if I would know for sure I would not ask :)

Comment: IE 8 (and Vista & above) run the IE processes in low-rights containers, which don't allow sending messages to higher-rights windows & processes.  Sandboxie doesn't show any screenshots of the sandboxed window, so I can't tell for sure, but you can't run separate window stations on the same desktop

Comment: I just analysed a calc.exe sandboxed window with "inspect.exe" . It has the same structure than the normal one, which indicates that my "rerender-theory" seems to be wrong. But what then is the purpose of the windowstation sandboxie creates?

Comment: You would have to ask them.  I have no idea.